# Método genérico no DbSet do DbContext com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc, dbset

Tenho uma aplicação em `C#` que utiliza `Entity Framework`.

Todos os meus `DbSet` do `DbContext`, eu estendo eles para ter uma busca padrão para o grid, abaixo exemplo do método.

```
public static GridDTO GridPadrao(this DbSet<Cliente> entities, ParametrosGridDTO parametros, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado) 
{
  // Código de busca
}
```

Porém para fazer a chamada eu faço conforme abaixo, tenho que colocar `if` para cada `DbSet`.

```
else if (parametros.tipoPesquisa == "Cliente")
    return db.Cliente.GridPadrao(parametros, usuarioLogado);
else if (parametros.tipoPesquisa == "Filial")
    return db.Filial.GridPadrao(parametros, usuarioLogado);
```

#### Dúvida

Tem alguma forma de eu chamar o `GridPadrao` de forma genérica? Sem precisar colocar `if` para cada `DbSet` que existe no `DbContext`.

#### Exemplos

```
public static GridDTO GridPadrao(this DbSet<Cliente> entities, ParametrosGridDTO parametros, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado)
{
    return new GridDTO(
        entities
            .Where(w => w.Apagado == "N" && w.VisaoID == usuarioLogado.VisaoID)
            .Where(MontaWhere(parametros), parametros.filtro.ToLowerNull())
            .Select(s => new { s.ClienteID, Nome = s.Pessoa.Nome, CNPJCPF = s.Pessoa.CNPJCPF, Fixo = s.Fixo == "S" ? "Sim" : "Não" })
            .OrderBy(MontaOrderBy(parametros))
            .Skip(parametros.itensParaIgnorar)
            .Take(parametros.itensPorPagina)
            .ToArray(),
        entities.TotalDeRegistros(parametros, usuarioLogado)
    );
}
```

e

```
public static GridDTO GridPadrao(this DbSet<Funcao> entities, ParametrosGridDTO parametros, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado)
{
    var setorID = Convert.ToInt32(parametros.filtrofixo);

    return new GridDTO(
        entities
            .Where(w => w.SetorID == setorID && w.Apagado == "N" && w.VisaoID == usuarioLogado.VisaoID)
            .Where(MontaWhere(parametros), parametros.filtro.ToLowerNull())
            .Select(s => new { s.FuncaoID, s.Sigla, s.Descricao })
            .OrderBy(MontaOrderBy(parametros))
            .Skip(parametros.itensParaIgnorar)
            .Take(parametros.itensPorPagina)
            .ToArray(),
        entities.TotalDeRegistros(parametros, usuarioLogado)
    );
}
```

Comment: O método grid padrão é definido uma vez pra cada entidade, certo? Tem como postar pelo menos dois deles? Porque, se eles forem parecidos, dá pra unir tudo.

Comment: @jefersonb adicionei dois exemplos.

Comment: É, não vai dar pra unir tudo. Eu pensei em criar um contrato entre as entidades, mas interfaces não permitem criação de métodos estáticos. Bom, preciso me ausentar uns minutos, tento pensar em algo quando eu voltar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tem alguma forma de eu chamar o `GridPadrao` de forma genérica?

Sim. Usando genéricos.

```
public static DbSetExtensions
{
    public static GridDTO GridPadrao<T>(this IDbSet<T> entities, ParametrosGridDTO parametros, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado)
        where T: class
    {
        // Código
    }
}
```

O problema é que você usou uma série de tipagens fortes aí. Possivelmente o método terá que ser inteiro redesenhado para funcionar genericamente.

Comment: E como faço para a partir de uma string, ter o DbSet? Além disto, teria que pensar um jeito de ter os campos do select, where e order by, isto seria possivel? Seria um repositorio?

Comment: Por que você quer obter o DbSet a partir de uma string? Acho que você está complicando muito. Um caminho seria usar Reflection + Attributes, mas com certeza isso vai ficar enorme.

Comment: A minha ideia era deixar de ter o `if`. Mas pelo jeito é mais fácil deixar assim para não complicar demais.